# NestJS @render path template

Tags: model-view-controller, nestjs

I have Nestjs MVC controller.

This code works fine:

```
  @Get()
  @Render('index')
  findAll() {
    return {};
  }
```

What the right way to define path to subfolders where template located?

This code return 404:

```
  @Get()
  @Render('path/to/template')
  findAll() {
    return {};
  }
```

Comment: What do you set as the view directory and what is the path to the file?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) The path specified in the `@Render()` depends on what is the path specified in the `main.ts` file for `setBaseViewsDir()`.

```
...
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
...
```

If you have this setting, then your `path/to/template` should be a path starting from the `views` directory.